# How to display a thumb image in the laravel calendar?

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

I want to show a thumb image and a text in the calendar cells. The text is getting displayed but I am not able to show the image.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($drama as $d) {
   // echo $d->id;
    if($d->show_date > date('yyyy-mm-dd'))
    {
      $drama_thumb = DB::table('dramas')->where('id',$d->drama_id)->get();
      $events[] = \Calendar::event(
        $drama_thumb[0]->drama_thumb.$d->show_title, //event title
        true, //full day event?
        $d->show_date, //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        $d->show_date, //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        'stringEventId' //optionally, you can specify an event ID
      );
    }

  }
```

Here is the static event() method definition:

```
$event = \Calendar::event(
"Valentine's Day", //event title
true, //full day event?
'2015-02-14', //start time, must be a DateTime object or valid DateTime format (bit.ly/1z7QWbg)
'2015-02-14' //end time, must be a DateTime object or valid DateTime format (bit.ly/1z7QWbg),
1, //optional event ID
[
    'url' => 'full-calendar.io'
]
```

);

Comment: are you sure about this part `$drama_thumb[0]->drama_thumb.echo`?

Comment: would you please provide the code for the static method `event()`, it's the one responsible for echoing the values.

Comment: Nope the implementation itself, this is the method call.

Comment: Do you have PHP experience?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120688/discussion-between-mina-abadir-and-prajakta).

Comment: anyone has any idea please do share...

Comment: Check the chat, I have sent you more comments there.